# How can I convert a Control's appearance to an image?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a user to be able to drag a `Control` while showing it. I can't seem to find a way to convert its appearance to an image (in order to convert that image into an icon in order to have that as the dragging icon).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to draw the control to an image? Use [`Control.DrawToBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx):

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(myControl.Width, myControl.Height);
myControl.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height));
```

Comment: I find it odd that a couple of searches didn't get me this simple answer, and one of them even said it can't be done in C# (perhaps it's from an earlier version of .net).

Comment: hi @minitech, sorry I know is long, but I would like to ask is it possible to use this for AjaxControlToolkit control?

Comment: @FeliciaSoh: This is about Windows Forms. It doesn’t apply to ASP.NET at all. Sorry!

Comment: @minitech, oh I see..ok thanks for your reply! I will think of other solution.