# Drawing controls on screen Winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a drag drop operation in my flowLayoutPanel . Now when dragging some control, I want that control to be showed with mouse moving on mouse coordinates.

I have this in my main class

```
Panel dragAble = new Panel();
```

in my dragDrop event I have this

```
dragAble.Width = item.Width;
dragAble.Height = item.Height;
dragAble.Left = e.X;
dragAble.Top = e.Y;
```

Where I assign the new control's(which have to be showed ) Width and Height to dragging Width and Height. and setting it's coordinates to mouse coordinates.

I need to draw it on dragEnter event handler. How to show it on screen ?

It's the same in Windows, when dragging a file or folder, you can see it when dragging.

Comment: How about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868941/how-to-allow-user-to-drag-a-dynamically-created-control-at-the-location-of-his-c

Comment: I need something like this
http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/04/mac_drag_drop1.png

See when dragging with mouse u can see the dragable control too.

Comment: Do you need to be able to drag between forms or just over a single form?

Comment: Did you see [my answer to your previous nearly-identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22787553/939213)?

Comment: Yes ispiro, I saw, but could not use it :/ 

Mike, only on one form

Comment: Means did not understand what are u saying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Drag-and-Drop: Show the dragged item while dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240603/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-show-the-dragged-item-while-dragging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can to handle this issue using the MouseDown,MouseMove,MouseUp events
create a boolean flag like IsMouseDown=false
on MouseDown set IsMouseDown to true
on MouseMove check if flage is true then change the left and top properties dragAble.Left = e.X;
dragAble.Top = e.Y;
on MouseUp  just set IsMouseDown to false

Comment: This is not going to address the question.  The question is how to draw it.

Comment: Yes, how to draw that new control on the mouse posiition

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine a custom cursor like isipro recommended with the tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx

It's a bit more work than you'd probably like, but it's also a reasonably complicated problem.

EDIT:
Here's some code that does what you ask for.  It could be engineered better, but it gets the point across:

```
class Dragger
{
    private readonly Form _parent;
    private Panel _dragee;

    public Dragger(Form parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public void MouseMoved(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragee != null)
        {
            _dragee.Location = _parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }

    public void StartDragging(Panel panel)
    {
        _dragee = panel;
    }

    public void StopDragging()
    {
        _dragee = null;
    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Dragger _dragger;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dragger = new Dragger(this);
        panel1.MouseMove += _dragger.MouseMoved;
        panel1.MouseDown += panel1_MouseDown;
        panel1.MouseUp += panel1_MouseUp;
    }

    void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _dragger.StopDragging();
    }

    void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        _dragger.StartDragging((Panel)sender);
    }

}
```

Important notes:  if you click the panel and drag it, the object itself is the thing which starts generating mousemove events.  So you have to listen to them, not to the form itself.  You'll also need to make sure that the dragged control is in front.

Good luck - and really, the custom cursor is the way to go :)

Comment: Means I have to make a new cursor ? Can't I just draw that control on the mouse position just Mike?

Comment: That's probably a bad idea - you'll have to draw the cursor on top, and it'll probably look pretty ugly.  A custom cursor is the _right_ answer.  Dynamically moving a control, while _an_ answer, will be more problematic.  That said, I'll have a play and see what I can work out for a hack.

Comment: have you got anything new Mike ?

Comment: I'm glad.  Please mark it as an answer if it has solved your problem :)