# Save Live Charts image

Tags: c#, image, winforms, livecharts

I need to save and print an image from [cartesian live chart](https://lvcharts.net), I've searched in [docs and tutorials](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Basics) but I can't find anything. How can I do this? I'm using WinForms and C# with Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that the graph itself does not support printing / taking screens to image, I would suggest creating this functionality Yourself.

**What are You going to need?**

1. Take screen shot - [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

-

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
// capture entire screen, and save it to a file
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
// display image in a Picture control named imageDisplay
this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
// capture this window, and save it
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\temp2.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
```

*In case You need just printscreen of control:* [C# Take ScreenShot of .net control within application and attach to Outlook Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000603/c-sharp-take-screenshot-of-net-control-within-application-and-attach-to-outlook)

-

```
public static void TakeCroppedScreenShot( string fileName, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageFormat format)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.CopyFromScreen(r.Left, r.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    bmp.Save(fileName, format);
}
```

2. Print the screen shot - [Print images c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750659/print-images-c-net)

-

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
...
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
    pd.Print();       
}

private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:\\Foto.jpg");
    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply convert the graph control to a bitmap as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180168/6649339) and then save it to a file. Using the graph control (`cartesianChart1`) from the LiveCharts [example](https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/blob/master/Examples/WinForms/Cartesian/BasicLine/BasicLineExample.cs):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(cartesianChart1.Width, cartesianChart1.Height);
cartesianChart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
bmp.Save("C:\\graph.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

This works even if your graph is behind another window.

Use [Tatranskymedved's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113163/6649339) to print the image.